# Why isn't my Windows Bootloader showing up?

Tags: windows-7, linux, multi-boot

I am working currently on a dual boot between Windows 7 and Linux.
I removed the GRUB bootloader successfully, because i wanted to use the Windows Bootloader.

Now, i used EasyBCD and some knowledge of 'bcdedit' to edit the Boot Manager, but, when i restart my computer, the boot manager isn't showing up, it just automaticlly boots into Windows.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Did you install EasyBCD's bootloader - NeoGrub?

Instructions from [here](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/NeoGrub):

1. Launch EasyBCD
2. Go to the "Add/Remove Entries" Screen.
3. Navigate to the "NeoGrub" tab in the "Add an Entry" section.
4. Select "Install NeoGrub"
5. Wait for the "Installation Complete" notification.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

With EasyBCD i restored my BCD, now it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Run msconfig and check the boot tab. Vista and Windows 7 phased out the boot.ini of earlier Windows versions. Perhaps EasyBCD and bcdedit haven't completely catched up.